# How can i pass a string literal like ("~/test/foo") in mkdir function in C programming?

Tags: c, arguments, mkdir

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I create directory tree in C++/Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675039/how-can-i-create-directory-tree-in-c-linux)
>   [Why mkdir fails to work with tilde (~)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616595/why-mkdir-fails-to-work-with-tilde)

i'm trying to create a directory in a C program and i use the mkdir function.
My program is as follows:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>

 #define MKDIR(x)  mkdir(x)

 int main() {

      //If i do mkdir("foo"), the dir is created 

      mkdir("~/test/foo"); //Directory foo not created inside test dir
 }
```

The dir foo isn't created in Test dir.

But how can i achieve that?
Thanks, in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`mkdir()` function doesn't expand `~` shortcut, you'll have to pull the value from the `HOME` environment variable. (see `man getenv`).

Comment: Thanks, for replying. I tested with the HOME variable. In the program i have to make, i shall not create a dir in the home directory, but in a destination folder which is not in my home directory.Is there any other way to define the specific path of the mkdir function without using getenv?

Comment: If it's not in the home dir, then you can specify full path like `"/home/youraccount/test/foo"` as literal.

Comment: Yeah, it's working and i also used system("mkdir /test/foo") in order to create a dir.Is system() function slower that mkdir()?

Comment: tons slower. Of course you have the benefit of being able to run `mkdir -p`, but you have to escape the directory name if it contains spaces or something worse than that, you can, of course, use `exec*` to run `mkdir`, but, honestly, I think creating directories one by one (if you actually need `-p`) is easier. In short, if you're doing it in c — do it in c.

Answer (score 1):

check wordexp: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/wordexp.html

```
#include <wordexp.h>                                                            
#include <stdio.h>                                                              
int main() {                                                                    
  wordexp_t p;                                                                  
  if (wordexp("~/", &p, 0)==0) {                                                
    printf("%s\n", p.we_wordv[0]);                                              
    wordfree(&p);                                                               
  }                                                                             
  return 0;                                                                     
}
```